# jQuery Loop through Animation

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I want to loop through an animation. The animation works fine but the loop is not working. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
function loop(){
    $('.wuc-car').delay(5000).animate({"margin-left": "695px"}, "slow").delay(5000).animate({"margin-left": "40px"}, "slow");
}

loop();
```

Comment: How can we tell you where you're going wrong when you haven't told us what the problem is, and given us only a couple of lines of code?

Comment: For the record I wasn't the one who downvoted you.

Comment: Sorry for ranting then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with setInterval

```
setInterval( function() {
    $('.wuc-car').delay(5000).animate({"margin-left": "695px"}, "slow").delay(5000).animate({"margin-left": "40px"}, "slow");
    }, 10000 );
```